# can not update record in spring data jpa using @Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to update a record using the following method

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update Tab t set t.email = :email, t.title = :title where t.id = :id ")
void update(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("email") String email, @Param("title") String title);
```

my form is

```
<form:form commandName="tab" action="/app/updated">
    <form:input path="title"/>
    <form:input path="email"/>      
    <button>Update</button>
</form:form>
```

method in controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updated", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("tab") Tab tab) {          
    tabService.update(tab); 
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

finally `tabService.update(tab)` is

```
public void update(Tab tab) {               
    tabRepository.update(tab.getId(), tab.getEmail(), job.getTitle());
    saveJoint(tab);
}
```

interesting thing is when I submit the form I get this

```
Hibernate: update tab set email=?,title=? where id=?
```

on console output but when I see the result is not updated, any mistakes I'm making?

Comment: I see no obvious errors. Is the ID correct? Does the query work if you execute it directly in the DB?

Comment: @Arshad Ali is update process within transaction..??

Comment: @Tunaki yes the query work if you execute it directly in the DB!

Comment: @ankur-singhal Yes I think because of  `@Transactional` on `update()`.

Comment: @ArshadAli try putting `@Transactional`

Comment: There is no id in your form, hence no id in the `Tab` object it is trying to update a record with id `null` which probably updates nothing.

Comment: @M.Deinum that was causing the issue, I added it as `<form:hidden path="id"/>`, then the update works. Thanks for pointing out.